# How do I rewrite this java function in scala keeping the same Optional input parameter?

Tags: java, scala, option-type, scala-option

I have the following method in java

```
protected <T> T getObjectFromNullableOptional(final Optional<T> opt) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(opt).flatMap(innerOptional -> innerOptional).orElse(null);
}
```

It takes a java `Optional` that can itself be `null` (I know, this is really bad and we're going to fix this eventually). And it wraps it with another `Optional` so it becomes either `Some(Optional<T>)` or `None`. Then it's `flatMapped`, so we get back `Optional<T>` or `None`, and finally apply `orElse()` to get `T` or `null`.

How do I write the same method with the same java.util.Optional in scala?

```
protected def getObjectFromNullableOptional[T >: Null](opt : Optional[T]): T =
    ???
```

I tried

```
protected def getObjectFromNullableOptional[T >: Null](opt : Optional[T]): T =
  Optional.ofNullable(opt).flatMap(o  => o).orElse(null)
```

But this gives me a `Type mismatch` error

> Required: Function[_ >: Optional[T], Optional[NotInferedU]]
>
> Found: Nothing => Nothing

I tried

```
protected def getObjectFromNullableOptional[T >: Null](opt : Optional[T]): T =
  Option(opt).flatMap(o => o).getOrElse(null)
```

But this gives me

> Cannot resolve overloaded method 'flatMap'

**Edit** I neglected to mention I'm using scala 2.11. I believe @tefanobaghino's solution is for scala 2.13 but it guided me towards the right path. I put my final solution in comments under this solution

Comment: IMO returning `null` instead of an option / optional is not a good idea. The output should be `Option[T]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last error raises a few suspicions: it looks like you're wrapping a Java `Optional` in a Scala `Option`. I would have instead have expected this to have failed because you're trying to `flatMap` to a different type, something like

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.Optional[T] => java.util.Optional[T]
 required: java.util.Optional[T] => Option[?]
```

This seems to fulfill your requirement:

```
import java.util.Optional

def getObjectFromNullableOptional[T](opt: Optional[T]): T =
  Optional.ofNullable(opt).orElse(Optional.empty).orElse(null.asInstanceOf[T])

assert(getObjectFromNullableOptional(null) == null)
assert(getObjectFromNullableOptional(Optional.empty) == null)
assert(getObjectFromNullableOptional(Optional.of(1)) == 1)
```

You can play around with this [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kPljGPb4Td6oueYPqQucVQ).

Note that `asInstanceOf` is compiled to a cast, not to an actual method call, so this code will not throw a `NullPointerException`.

You can also go into something closer to your original solution by helping Scala's type inference a bit:

```
def getObjectFromNullableOptional[T](opt: Optional[T]): T =
  Optional.ofNullable(opt).flatMap((o: Optional[T]) => o).orElse(null.asInstanceOf[T])
```

Or alternatively using Scala's `identity`:

```
def getObjectFromNullableOptional[T](opt: Optional[T]): T =
  Optional.ofNullable(opt).flatMap(identity[Optional[T]]).orElse(null.asInstanceOf[T])
```

For a solution using Scala's `Option` you can do something very close:

```
def getObjectFromNullableOption[T](opt: Option[T]): T =
  Option(opt).getOrElse(None).getOrElse(null.asInstanceOf[T])
```

Note that going to your `flatMap` solution with Scala's `Option` allows you to avoid having to be explicit about the function type:

```
def getObjectFromNullableOption[T](opt: Option[T]): T =
  Option(opt).flatMap(identity).getOrElse(null.asInstanceOf[T])
```

I'm not fully sure about the specifics, but I believe the issue is that, when using `java.util.Optional` you are passing a Scala `Function` to `Optional.flatMap`, which takes a Java `Function`. The Scala compiler can convert this automatically for you but apparently you have to be specific and explicit about type for this to work, at least in this case.

A note about your original code: you required `T` to be a supertype of `Null` but this is not necessary.

You have a better context regarding what you are doing, but as a general advice it's usually better to avoid having `null`s leak in Scala code as much as possible.

Comment: I neglected to mention I'm on scala 2.11 so I had to modify your suggestion slightly to get it working: `Optional.ofNullable(opt).orElse(Optional.empty[T]).orElse(null.asInstanceOf[T])`